# How to match whitespace in the string with bash?

Tags: bash, globbing

```
ls
Session 9 - Terminal Value.mp4
```

Now i want to delete it.

```
shopt -s dotglob
rm -rf  .*.mp4
```

It take no effect,the file `Session 9 - Terminal Value.mp4` remains there.Maybe `.` can't match whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotglob` is used to match filenames starting with a `.` (dotfiles) which are otherwise hidden when glob patterns are used (unless the `.` is explicitly present in the pattern).

Example:

```
$ shopt dotglob
dotglob         off
$ touch .lala
$ ls *lala
ls: cannot access '*lala': No such file or directory
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ shopt dotglob
dotglob         on
$ ls *lala
.lala
```

Your pattern `.*.mp4` matches filenames starting with a literal `.` followed by any string `*`, followed by `.mp4`.

It would match filename `.Session 9 - Terminal Value.mp4` for example (with or without `dotglob` enabled, since the first `.` is present in the pattern).

Since globbing also matches space characters, all you need is

```
rm *.mp4
```